# Matplotlib plot style

Tags: python, matplotlib

Two questions:
-My y axis values have a space from the x axis, and I want it to be closen
-How do I add a color to everything, background ofthe image and graph.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You want to change the `xmin` and `ymin` properties of the axis.

Note the the function is almost invisible near the origin.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# oh yes, y is quite flat about the origin
t = np.linspace(0, 1.57, 158)
y = t**5*np.cos(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')

# change the colors of the graph and of the figure
fig.set_facecolor('k')
ax.set_facecolor('C3')

# change the colors of the text elements
plt.rc('axes', labelcolor='w')
plt.rc('xtick', color='w')
plt.rc('ytick', color='w')
plt.rc('text',  color='w')

# plot y and label it properly
ax.plot(t, y, color='xkcd:pink', lw=2)
plt.xlabel('X', size='xx-large')
plt.ylabel('Y', size='x-large')
plt.title('As You Like It', color='xkcd:pink', size='xx-large')

###############################################################
# remove the despised space ###################################
plt.axis(xmin=0, ymin=0) ######################################
###############################################################

plt.show()
```

I'd suggest to remove `plt.axis(...)` and use `plt.grid(1)`, obtaining the figure below.

[image]